# Power BI: Calculate sum of variance based on the variance % of last year

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a requirement where I need to calculate the sum(term reductions) of all the [variance] for which the [variance %] of the last year-end is less than or equal to -1.

For this, I'm using this formula:

```
Term Reductions = 
var _date = MAX('Date-Processing'[Date])
var _month = MONTH(_date)
var _prior_year_end_date = IF(_month=1,EOMONTH(_date,-13),EOMONTH(_date,-_month))
var _prior_year_end_variance = CALCULATE([Variance %],FILTER(ALL('Date-Processing'),'Date-Processing'[Date]=_prior_year_end_date),FILTER(AccountLoan,AccountLoan[RiskRatingCategoryCode]<>"S" && AccountLoan[RiskRatingCategoryCode]<>"W"))

return SUMX(SUMMARIZE(Customer,Customer[CustomerName],"Variance",if(_prior_year_end_variance<=-1,[Variance],BLANK())),[Variance])
```

The formula is showing value if overall(all customers) [variance %] is less than or equal to -1, or else it is showing blank.

Can anyone please help me to understand, how can I calculate [variance %] at the customer level, so that even if the overall [variance %] is greater than -1, but any customer has [variance %] less than or equal to -1, then the output should be the sum of [variance] of those customers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly I think you just need to move your prior year calculation into the SUMX table:

```
Term Reductions = 
var _date = MAX('Date-Processing'[Date])
var _month = MONTH(_date)
var _prior_year_end_date = IF(_month=1,EOMONTH(_date,-13),EOMONTH(_date,-_month))

return SUMX(
  SUMMARIZE(Customer,
    Customer[CustomerName],
    "PriorEnd", CALCULATE([Variance %],FILTER(ALL('Date-Processing'),'Date-Processing'[Date]=_prior_year_end_date),FILTER(AccountLoan,AccountLoan[RiskRatingCategoryCode]<>"S" && AccountLoan[RiskRatingCategoryCode]<>"W")),
    "Variance", [Variance]), 
  IF([PriorEnd]<=-1,[Variance],BLANK()))
```